# popover UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm new to iPad App development (not to iPhone Development). I wish to show a split view controller as a popover when a particular button is clicked [Everything's in interface builder]. So I drag and dropped a Split View Controller and then made a segue from the button to the split view controller. I have set the size of Split View Controller as Form Sheet. Now in the iPad simulator I expect the popover to have both Master View Controller and Detail View Controller, however only the rootViewController (Master) is appearing and there is no scrolling too (in the popover).

How can I show both the master and detail view controller in my popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to do that:

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html)

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I think that rules out the option of presenting it modally too, right ??

Comment: Yes it does. I don't know if it would work or not, but the doc says you shouldn't do it.